# Is base tag really necessary for relative URLs?

Tags: html, url

I'm using relative URLs for my websites (`href="/something/"`), and it works perfect. I recently discovered the `<base>` tag. Should I be using it? What could go wrong if I don't use it? At the moment, it seems web browsers can solve the domain perfectly without this tag. Even web crawlers can solve the absolute path perfectly...

Will it be a deprecated tag soon?

Comment: You shouldn’t use it unless you have to. And apparently you don’t. So, don’t.

Comment: I disagree with this: «This question is opinion-based». It's a technical question  with a technical answer. It's about the usecase of an HTML tag, and hopefully it will be useful for others, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have a `<base>` element, the browser will use the current address to resolve relative URIs.

If you *do* supply a `<base>` element, you basically tell the browser to use the uri you supplied *instead* of the browsers address.

So you don't need it normally, *unless* you want to tell the browser to use a different base than the current address.